# Finding the average of the maximums among a sequence of odd integers

Tags: python

The question goes like this- Given an input of a set of integers, find the average of maximum values from each sequence of consecutive odd integers in the input.
For example: 3,5,2,21,13,5,6,3,5,5,7
This input instance has three sequences of consecutive odd integers (3,5),(21,13,5),(3,5,5,7). From this the maximum odd integers are 5, 21, and 7 respectively. The average of these is to be found.

```
lst=[3,5,2,21,13,5,6,3,5,5,7]

s=set()
odd=[]
i=0
m=0
for loop in range(len(lst)):
    while(i<len(lst)):
        if lst[i]%2!=0:
            odd.append(lst[i])
            m=max(odd)
        else:
            for k in range(i,len(lst)):
                if lst[k]%2!=0:
                    i=k
                    break
        i+=1

    s.add(m)
    odd=[]
print (sum(s)/len(s))
```

I keep a list of odd integers and find their maximum each time. When I encounter an even integer I just iterate and find the index of the next odd integer. I keep all my maximums in a set so that they don't repeat, and finally print the average. 
However the average I'm getting is 13 instead of 11.
What is wrong with the logic?

Comment: If you don't keep duplicate maxima, you won't get the average. What is the average of 20, 20, 20, 20 and 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task can be accomplished handily using `itertools.groupby` and `statistics.mean`.

```
from itertools import groupby
from statistics import mean

lst = [3,5,2,21,13,5,6,3,5,5,7]
print(mean(max(g) for k, g in groupby(lst, lambda x: x % 2) if k))
```

Comment: How do I use it with my sample input?

Answer (score 1):

You are using set which cannot contain duplicate elements. You don't need to track all the maxima, you can just add them and keep a count too.

```
lst=[3,5,2,21,13,5,6,3,5,5,7]

m=-1
sum=0
count=0
for loop in lst:
    if loop%2 !=0:
        if loop>m:
            m = loop
    else:
        sum += m;
        m = -1
        count += 1

if(m != -1):
    sum += m
    count += 1

print (sum/count)
```

Comment: And what if the list contains a sequence of negative odd integers, like -7, -5, -11?

Comment: What is the use of
`if(m != -1):
    sum += m
    count += 1`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I've assumed there are positive numbers only. If you want to include negative numbers, just change value of m to be less than the lower bound of the limit. if -1000<a[i]<1000 , then set m = -1001.

Comment: @DivyanshuVarma the sum and count are updated when an even element occurs, so the final sublist containing odd elements isn't updated and we have to do it manually. Eg - [3,5,7,2,9,11,13] . After visiting 13, loop ends and we have m = 13 which isn't included in the sum so we add it in the if else statement.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a much simpler way but this answer follows your logic:

```
lst=[3,5,2,21,13,5,6,3,5,5,7]

s=set()
odd=[]
i=0
m=0
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i]%2!=0:
        odd.append(lst[i])
        if i==len(lst)-1:
            m=max(odd)
            s.add(m)
    else:
        if len(odd) > 0:
            m=max(odd)
            s.add(m)
            odd=[]

print (s, sum(s)/len(s))
```

Comment: This fails if the list starts with an even number, like `lst=[2,21,13,5,6,3,5,5,7, 4]` : `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille thanks for pointing that out, you're right. I've added the length check.